# Regex replacing pairs of dollar signs

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like: `The old man $went$ to the $barn$.` How would I convert this to `The old man ~!went! to the ~!barn!.`

If I didn't need to add the `~` in front of the first occurrence, I could simply do `text.replace('$', '!')` in Python.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\$(\w+)\$', r'~!\1!', s)`

Comment: Or another one only matching dollars if they are inside word boundaries: `re.sub(r'\$\b([^$]+)\b\$', r'~!\1!', s)`. Does either of them or any answers below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group so that your replacement string can put the text between the `$` back in place.

So the regex would be:

```
\$([^$]*)\$
```

And then the replacement string would be:

```
~!\1!
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT8yR1/2)

Comment: Just to clarify, the difference between using `.*?` and `[^$]*` is that the first is "lazy" and the second is "greedy". Greedy quantifiers are faster, since they don't require trying to match the rest of the regex at each character. (12 steps vs 28 steps)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, regex this. Capture groups will help.

```
result = re.sub(r'\$(.*?)\$', r'~!\1!', my_str)
```

Comment: The dollar signs aren't escaped.

Comment: @Ramen Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Probably regex capturing group is the way to go here, but here a simple way to do it without regex:

```
>>> s
'The old man $went$ to the $barn$'
>>> r
''
>>> seen = False
>>> 
>>> for c in s:
        if c=='$':
            if seen:
                r +='!'
                seen = False
            else:
                r +='~!'
                seen=True
        else:
            r += c


>>> r
'The old man ~!went! to the ~!barn!'
```